# TypeError: "x" is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, discord, discord.js

So when I was coding a Discord bot, it suddenly just started saying stuff wasn't a function. And this applies to everything, it really just applies to anything and if I try to call a function then it says it's not a function. For example:

For example this line of code I have here:

```js
client.commandHandler(commandFolders, "./src/commands")
```

It says it's not a function, but I've defined it as a function:

```js
module.exports = (client) => {
    client.commandHandler = async (commandFolders, path) => {
        const cmds = [];
        for (const folder of commandFolders) {
            const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`${path}/${folder}`).filter(f => f.endsWith('.js'));
            for (const f of commandFiles) {
                const command = require(`${path}/${folder}/${f}`)
                cmds.push(command.data.toJSON());
            }
        }
}
}
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: have you included the command handler in main file?

Comment: I suspect your importing your export as `client` and then attempting to call `client.commandHandler()` - but, you've exported a function that takes a client as a parameter. Not an object (`client`) with a method named `commandHandler`.

Comment: @RandyCasburn we client is part of the Discord.js package, and I'm using that in my file where I define client.commandHandler... so this should then automatically I allow me to use it in any other file.

Comment: Could you provide the full error log / more of the related code?